# No route matches [GET] /users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

**Edit:** Resource and controller has been pluralized, thanks to the feedback wrote in comments. But my problem still persists.

I'm very new to Rails and I'm trying to create a REST API in Rails 4.
I've got a routing error when I try to execute a GET request on the `User` ressource : `http://api.localhost:3000/users`

> No route matches [GET] "/users"

But, when I execute the command 'rake routes' on my terminal, I can see that there is a `/users` route:

> ```
>     api_users GET    /users(.:format)          api/users#index {:subdomain=>"api"}
>               POST   /users(.:format)          api/users#create {:subdomain=>"api"}  
>  new_api_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      api/users#new {:subdomain=>"api"}
> edit_api_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) api/users#edit {:subdomain=>"api"}
>      api_user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      api/users#show {:subdomain=>"api"}
>               PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      api/users#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
>               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      api/users#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
>               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      api/users#destroy {:subdomain=>"api"}
> ```

Here is the content of my `route.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # create rousources in subdomain api
  namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do
    resources :users
  end

end
```

And the `users_controller.rb` file:

```
module Api
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

        def index
            @users = User.all

            render json: users, status: 200
        end

    end
end
```

Any suggestion?

**Edit:** Resource and controller has been pluralized, thanks to the feedback wrote in comments. But my problem still persists.

Comment: Besides your problem, you should follow the convention and pluralize your resource names as well as controller names.

Comment: Are you able to access any url that you listed? I believe @blelump is correct. Try editing your controller file name as well and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback about naming convention. In my database, the table which store data about users is named `user`. Should I rename it into `users` too?

Comment: I just edited my original post with the changes on the `users` resource and `users` controller

Comment: have you tried with `http://api.lvh.me:3000/users` (require internet access) instead of `http://api.localhost:3000/user` ?

Comment: @JeanLebrument - You mentioned `http://api.localhost:3000/user` while the url should be `http://api.localhost:3000/users` as you can clearly see in your routes, there is no route which points to `GET /user`. Is this a typo or is this what you tried ?

Comment: @anonymousxxx & @pamiosolanky: I tested `/users` not `/user`. I edited my original post to correct the mistake

Comment: Try configuring `127.0.0.1  api.localhost.com` (not just 127.0.0.1 _api.localhost_) in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails determines the `subdomain` of an URL by taking that part from a host address that is in front of the second dot from the right. In your example you use the host `api.localhost`. Rails would resolve an empty subdomain from that.

Therefore I suggest configuring a domain like `api.my_app.dev` in your `hosts` file. That would allow Rails to determine the correct `api` subdomain part from the host.

After you did that your local server can respond to `http://api.my_app.dev:3000/users`

Btw. I chose the top level domain `dev`, because it is the default if you use a tool like [POW](http://pow.cx/).

Answer (score 4):

you need configuire your hosts:

`sudo vim /etc/hosts`

add

`127.0.0.1  api.test.com`

then `rails s` and  view "http://api.test.com:3000/user"
it will work!

sorry about my Enlish, hope help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I've already configure my `hosts` file with: `127.0.0.1 api.localhost`. I access to my api using the url: `api.localhost:3000` An other idea ?

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do
```

it is false
you need to check  `root :to => 'adm001s#index'`